# ConstructorArgumentAttribute usage issue in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, markup-extensions

I created a custom markup extension like below

```
public class CME: MarkupExtension
{
    private Type _type;
    private string _typeName;

    public CME()
    {
    }

    public CME(Type type, string typeName)
    {
        this._type = type;
        this._typeName = typeName;
    }

    [ConstructorArgument("type")]
    public Type Type
    {
        get
        {
            return this._type;
        }

        set
        {
            this._type = value;
        }
    }

    [ConstructorArgument("typeName")]
    public string TypeName
    {
        get
        {
           return this._typeName;
        }

        set
        {
           this._typeName = value;
        }
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And I found I could still using `{local:CME {x:Type sys:Boolean},Bool}` to create instance of CME class in XAML even I remove all ConstructorArgumentAttribute in the CME class.

So I want to know why we need ConstructorArgumentAttribute in the custom markup extension implementation or what is the meaning of ConstructorArgumentAttribute.

Is there anyboday can help on this? Many thanks.